# How do I install hunspell on windows10?

Tags: python, hunspell

I'm new to python and need help with getting hunspell installed on my windows 10. The tool is PyCharm.

First I tried to install CyHunspell: `pip install CyHunspell` and got the following error msg:

```
RuntimeError: 'pkg-config' is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file.
```

Then I tried installing PyHunspell instead and got the following error msg:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement PyHunspell (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for PyHunspell
```

Then I tried installing hunspell directly and got the following error msg:

```
hunspell.cpp
    hunspell.cpp(20): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'hunspell.hxx': No such file or directory
    error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\BIN\\x86_amd64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
```

In my test code:

```py
import hunspell
```

Result:

```
spellchecker = hunspell.HunSpell() failed with the following error msg:
AttributeError: module 'hunspell' has no attribute 'HunSpell'
```

I would think I'm not the first one who uses hunspell on windows 10, but somehow I can't seem to find info needed to get this to work.

Comment: It looks like the Microsoft compiler is being used which would imply you're  not doing what is described for building it on Windows in the [`readme.md`](https://github.com/hunspell/hunspell) file of the project.

Comment: Thank you @Martineau. So for windows10, is there a compiled package that I can use, similar to other python packages through pip install? Or do I need to compile using Mingw64 and MSYS2 as specified in readme.md?

Comment: I looked in Christoph Gohlke's [Python Extension Packages for Windows](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/) which I've used a number of time to get pre-compiled packages in the past, but it doesn't have this one. This means you might have to build it yourself using one of the outlined methods.

Answer (score 10):

The GNU Emacs documentation states [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/efaq-w32/EZWinPorts.html) (underlined by me):

> The [EZWinPorts project](https://sourceforge.net/projects/ezwinports/) provides many useful ports of recent versions of GNU and Unix software. This includes all the optional libraries used by Emacs (image libraries, libxml2, GnuTLS), RCS, Texinfo, a clone of man command, Grep, xz, bzip2, bsdtar, ID Utils, Findutils, **Hunspell**, Gawk, GNU Make, Groff, GDB.

You will indeed find Hunspell in the [list of files](https://sourceforge.net/projects/ezwinports/files/) of the EZWinPorts project on sourceforge.

Once unzipped, you shall find the executable hunspell.exe inside the bin folder. No installation required. The tool is to be used on the command-line. You probably should add it to your Windows Path.

Tested on my Windows 10 PC.